# Cursor not showing in Device Mode (Google Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome

So I'm trying to develop a webapplication and I'm trying to check it out on mobile.
I'm currently using Cordova and JQuery Mobile together with ripple.js to view my application in my browser.

- The first issue (as far as I know) is that ripple.js will work best in Google Chrome, so this is my only test platform.
- The second issue is that when I toggle Device Mode on, it doesn't show me the black dot (cursor) when I enter the rendered version.

I'll explain my situation or a scenario:

1. As an example I'll go to http://google.com
2. I press F12 to enter developer mode
3. I click the Toggle Device Mode button 
   [image]
4. I will see my cursor, **until** I enter the generated mobile canvas. While I would normally see a black transparant dot, I now see nothing.
   I can however click and drag like I would normally do, but I can't see what I'm doing.

The things I already tried:

- Reset all the flags back to default
- Reset all developer tool settings to default
- **(edit)** Installed a previous version of Chrome AND Chromium

So question is, how do I get my cursor back?

Extra: I'm using version `49.0.2623.87 m`, but that's not related since my co-worker, has the same version and he sees the cursor.

**(edit)** currently I'm using the mouse option where I press Ctrl to see the circle which indicates where my cursor is, but this really has to be a temp solution.

**(edit)** I fixed it by doing a combination of things. So I'm not sure which exact thing fixed it. I removed a few programs that I installed after it still worked. I uninstalled about 4 of them. Also I did an update of my graphics card and then did a reboot. So it could be either the graphics card update, the software uninstall and/or the reboot.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had the same issue. (note this question might be a duplicate [of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36712750/how-to-show-mouse-pointer-in-responsive-mode))

Following the [advice on the Chrome forum here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633832#c9) I changed the Quantization Range in my Intel HD Graphics Control Panel from "Default Range" to "Full Range". The touch pointer (grey circle) appeared immediately.

If that doesn't help you may have to change refresh rate too. Changing from 59p Hz to 60p Hz or some other refresh rate might help.

Comment: Can't be a duplicate if I posted my question before him/her, but the suggestion on the chrome forum makes sense.

Comment: I've been part of an issue in the Chrome issue tracker to resolve this and this is the answer I needed! I finally have the touch pointer back!

Comment: I also had to change refresh rate from 59p Hz to 60p Hz.

Answer (score 11):

This should also help.

1. Open the mouse control panel.
2. Select the Pointer Options tab in the Mouse Properties window.
3. Then enable Display pointer trails option.
4. In case you don't like or are getting annoyed, like me, due to the trailer. Move the slider to the Short position and the trailer becomes near to non-existent or invisible.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it myself, yet I'm not exactly sure how I did it. I edited my original post and added the solution in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same on my Asus laptop with Chrome 66

Resolution that worked for me

1. Graphics Control Panel > Display > General Settings > Scaling > Change to Scale full screen.
2. OFF your Asus Eye Care Switcher.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as answer because above mentioned answer didn't work for me but I had this issue when I had a monitor attached to my laptop, for development work.  I played around with my display settings and discovered that IF the scale on my second monitor did not match the scale on my laptop, the mobile development mode cursor would disappear. (windows 10)

If this is an issue for anyone just go into Display settings -> Display -> Scale and Layout --> make sure that both your laptop/desktop matches the display scale of your second monitor.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Same issue - looks like changing the scaling to 125% makes the mobile view cursor appear, doesn't seem to matter what scaling or resolution the other monitor is.