# How to show mouse pointer in responsive mode?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I used to be able to uncheck a checkbox that said `Emulate touch screen` in the `Emulation/Sensors`-panel so that I could see a mouse pointer when using responsive mode. This panel is now gone, and the new sensors-panel doesn't have this setting.

This makes it impossible to use the responsive mode, as I have no pointer and no control where I touch/click (who designed this feature?!). How can I see a pointer/mouse when I use responsive mode in newer Chrome?

Answer (score 242):

Apparently, you're supposed to see a circle as your mouse when using responsive mode. I have never seen that, even using several different machines, so the feature seems broken.

Updated for v72:
[image: guide v72]

---

Older

However, right after posting this question, I finally stumbled upon a solution. In version 50, the solution is now to press the three dots `⋮` to the right in responsive mode, and select `Show device type`. This gives you a new dropdown next to the sizes etc., in which `Desktop` or `Mobile (no touch)` can be selected to use a normal mouse pointer (disable touch emulation) while using responsive mode.

[image: Guide]

Comment: Thanks, still relevant in 2017, this bug was driving me nuts!

Comment: In my version of Chrome on macOS Sierra, it's labelled "add device type"

Comment: watch out - there are two 'three dots' icons, one in the elements panel and the other (the one you want) in the main browser window. Especially if you have a really wide screen and you have devtools docked to the left it's easy to miss the second one!

Comment: In my version of Chrome on Win 10 it is also called "Add device type" but when I click it I see a dropdown menu added with the word "mobile" - but the menu is greyed out and disabled. Turns out, I had first selected "iPhone 6/7/8". If I change that to "Responsive", then the menu becomes active. I do not understand why Google would make it so there is no way you can use your mouse pointer while emulating an iPhone.

Comment: But, now in 2019, Chrome has removed this option too... any other ideas?

Comment: @Codesmith make sure you have selected `Responsive` and not an iPhone or something, then you can select desktop.

Comment: Sorry @Matsemann, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using Chrome v72. I do not have "Show device type" in that menu in the picture next to '2', nor do I have "Desktop" available in the dropdown beside '3' (in fact, this dropdown seems to instead adjust simulated network connection quality), and I haven't switched it off of "Responsive." Any thoughts?

Comment: @Codesmith updated image for how it looks on v72 here

Comment: Omgosh, I see it now! Thanks a ton. I thought 'Add device type' was something completely different. +1 :)

Comment: Note that there is also an option in the device type dropdown for "Mobile (no touch)". Per [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/#type), this keeps the rendering method as mobile, though I'm not sure what that really changes.

Comment: This doesn't fix anything, it just selects a different mode. There used to be a circle pointer when emulating touch mode, now it's gone. Using non-touch mode is a kind of a workaround, but not a solution.

Answer (score 55):

Go to: Control Panel > Intel Graphics Settings > Display > General Settings. Then change Quantization Range to **Full Range**. Solution from [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633832#c9).

[image]

Thank @Funktr0n.

Comment: This fixed my problem, but why?

Comment: The screenshot was really helpful. Appreciate it.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I use my laptop at home and the cursor appears just fine, but when I plug it into a different monitor at work the cursor disappears. This answer fixed the problem! I assume this is a strange monitor issue.

Comment: keeps getting this every time i replug in the monitor :/ after applying settings again it works again (althoug it still seems to be onfull range before)

Comment: I connected 2 monitors to my laptop. this problem occured on one monitor (brand: AOC) , other one is ok.

Comment: I've got 2 identical monitors, 1 (VGA) showed the cursor and the other (HDMI) didn't! This solved it for me! Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed my problem as well. And my colors look much nicer now. But what does this setting have to do with a touch cursor? Just asking to understand what the hell I just did...

Answer (score 34):

In Chrome `Version 73.0.3683.103` and macOS Mojave you have to toggle `add device type` button in the menu of browser window in dev mode to see the device type dropdown: [image]

And the select typo of device you need:
[image]

Comment: This works for me on Mac with latest Chrome (v99 as of March 2022)

Comment: Thank-you, still relevant in v109.x (Feb 2023)

Answer (score 10):

The answer is pretty straightforward. Chrome gives you an option to create a custom device.  Follow these steps:
 1. Open dev tools 
 2. Press F1 to get into settings 
 3. go to devices
 4. Add a custom device there.

The IMPORTANT THING: When you create a custom device, choose the option "Mobile (No Touch)". That's it, cursor would be visible when you select this device for emulation.

Comment: Note that you have to close and reopen the tab.

Answer (score 8):

This should also help.

1. Open the mouse control panel.
2. Select the Pointer Options tab in the Mouse Properties window.
3. Then enable Display pointer trails option.
4. In case you don't like or are getting annoyed, like me, due to the trailer. Move the slider to the Short position and the trailer becomes very short.

Answer (score 8):

Press `Ctrl + Shift + C` while the mouse is over the page in order to turn "Select an element in the page to inspect it" mode on then turn it back off using the icon and not the shortcut. Your cursor is now visible :)

[image]

Another way is to **disable touch simulation** by selecting no touch in "Emulated Devices" (in devtools settings):

[image]

**Note that you may have to close and reopen the tab.**

Comment: The second part of this answer seems to be ok, but I want to retain the width-sliders  and not have a fixed size device. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Warning:** this is only a quick hack, not a fix

If you right click over the emulated device picture you'll be able to keep the pointer visible so you'll at least see where you're clicking.

[image]

Hopefully this will get resolved soon.

Comment: I love the "hackiness" of this solution!

Answer (score 3):

It appears the non-existent touch cursor in Device Mode is an actual issue, and it's [being tracked here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633832&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools%20&colspec=ID%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified%20Stars)

Comment: Changing the Quantization Range in my Intel HD Graphics Control Panel fixed this problem for me. Thanks @Funktr0n  : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633832#c9

Answer (score 2):

What solved my issue was setting the refresh rate of my monitor to 60Hz progressive! I don't know how it got set on 59Hz interlaced.

[image]

**Added: What ACTUALLY solved my problem was swaping the connection from HDMI to DisplayPort! I dont know weather it was the cable problem or the port. Finally the cursor is there and working!**

Answer (score 0):

This is a Display Drive Issue, For a simple solution press and hold SHIFT key and a cursor will be visible on device.

BUT do click on link only WITHOUT holding SHIFT [else it will open that link in new window]